# How to display validation error and other errors together in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my controller there are a bunch of validations. After validating them I check if a certain element is present in the session. If that element is absent then I send another error. I want to show all the validation error and other error together.

```
 $this->validate($request,[
        'other11' => 'nullable|image',
        'other12' => 'nullable|image',
        'other13' => 'nullable|image',
        'other14' => 'nullable|image',
        'other15' => 'nullable|image',
    ]);

    if(session()->get('media')['other10']==NULL)
    {
        return back()->withErrors(['other10'=>'No data in session']);
    }
```

Currently, if there is a validation error then the error regarding 'other10' field is not displayed in the view. Is there a way to return both the validation error and the error regarding 'other10' together to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a validator instance with all the validation rules, then you can take its errors and add as many errors as you want to it.  It's something like the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'other11' => 'nullable|image',
    'other12' => 'nullable|image',
    'other13' => 'nullable|image',
    'other14' => 'nullable|image',
    'other15' => 'nullable|image'
]);

$errors = $validator->errors();

if (session()->get('media')['other10'] == NULL) {
    $errors->add('other10', 'No data in session');
}

return back()->withErrors($errors);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'other11' => 'nullable|image',
]);
```

This will redirect back if any error message, validation fails. After that, print messages in view like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('other11'))
    {{ $errors->first('email') }}
@endif
```

If you want to print all messages, this will help you:

```
@if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Better to use Laravel Form Request validation snipped code from Laravel:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: I know how to display error messages. I want to send both errors together.

For example, if there is a validation error then I can't show the error regarding other10 field.

Comment: $errors = $validator->errors();

    if (session()->get('media')['other10'] == NULL) {
        $errors->add('other10', 'No data in session');
    }   this will restrict to send specific error messages , dont need to return redirect back , laravel automatically redirect you back , if any validation fails

Comment: This issue is solved thanks to "Ahmed Nour Jamal El-Din".

But for the sake of future, please show me how I can write the logic regarding the 'other10' field inside the "validate" method.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
return redirect()->back()->with('error' ,'error message');
```

instead of

```
return back()->withErrors(['other10'=>'No data in session']);
```